# hdfs core node disk full, investigation?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, cluster-computing, diskspace

We have a spark cluster on top of hdfs on aws with 2 core nodes and 1 master. Recently I discovered that all jobs were failing because the disk on both the core nodes was full. Upon further investigation it was found that :

`/data/var/lib/hadoop/dfs/current/BP-*/current/finalized/subdir*/*`   was full. I am able to see the data but what I would like to figure out is which job actually created these files which took up almost 600-700GB of space so we can prevent this from happening in the future. Could someone please advise where/how I might start the investigation?

Comment: Same problem, this is discovered using shell commands not HDFS, which doesn't show this path. What are these files? You don't see them with `dfs -ls ...` as far as I can tell.

Comment: The same issue happening with, did you find something?

Answer (score 0):

Check the UI of the job on 4040....you might find something. 
Otherwise, please tell some more details about the job, data and environment.